# Unable to configure NTP on Cisco Switch ws-C3560x-48p

Tags: cisco, ntp

I want to sync time of Cisco Switch (ws-C3560x) with AD server. After following configurations the time is not synchronized. Pl guide.

```
#show running-config | include ntp

ntp logging
ntp server 150.153.0.1

#show ntp associations detail

150.153.0.1 configured, insane, invalid, stratum 1
ref ID .LOCL., time DEB7AE26.A40A8163 (15:47:02.640 utc Tue May 29 2018)
our mode client, peer mode server, our poll intvl 64, peer poll intvl 64
root delay 0.00 msec, root disp 10725.96, reach 3, sync dist 10746.93
delay 1.73 msec, offset -1498763705.0000 msec, dispersion 15.69
precision 2**6, version 4
org time DEB89DE5.542B45FE (08:49:57.328 utc Wed May 30 2018)
rec time D13E13FE.595759A8 (01:41:34.348 utc Thu Mar 31 2011)
xmt time D13E13FE.58A6DEAF (01:41:34.346 utc Thu Mar 31 2011)
filtdelay =     2.69    2.96    2.04    2.45    1.73    2.39    1.73    2.82
filtoffset = -149876 -149876 -149876 -149876 -149876 -149876 -149876 -149876
filterror =    15.63   15.66   15.69   15.72   15.75   15.78   15.81   15.84
minpoll = 6, maxpoll = 10

#show ntp status

Clock is unsynchronized, stratum 16, no reference clock
nominal freq is 190.7348 Hz, actual freq is 190.7348 Hz, precision is 2**17
reference time is 00000000.00000000 (05:00:00.000 utc Mon Jan 1 1900)
clock offset is 0.0000 msec, root delay is 0.00 msec
root dispersion is 1.42 msec, peer dispersion is 0.00 msec
loopfilter state is 'FSET' (Drift set from file), drift is 0.000000000 s/s
system poll interval is 64, never updated.
```

Comment: Your AD server is not a Stratum 1 NTP server. I seriously doubt it is directly connected to an atomic clock.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have your local time on the router within 4000 seconds of the NTP server time in order for NTP to sync. Your difference is too high for NTP to sync.

You can also enable `debug ntp validity` to get further information as to why your NTP source is not considered valid, but in your case it's clearly a very high clock difference.